# Get Method is not working inside App if URL contains .info?

Tags: objective-c, json, https, get, afnetworking

I am making a simple GET Method inside the APP , But its Not Working on some URL..

For Eg :

https://lievensberg.webcamconsult.com/wachtkamer/ZwXIk9KcYvMBFeJWiSeUQQ.json . - this is working (contains .com)

https://soa-webcamconsult.sense.info/wachtkamer/pk3rs51FpFUQkrHOJ0uBHg.json  - this is not working (contains .info)

Both URL is Working Perfect in Browser...!

I am using AFNetworking, Any one can Help Me Please ?
This is the Call Method , Url given below

//https://soa-webcamconsult.sense.info/wachtkamer/pk3rs51FpFUQkrHOJ0uBHg.json

```
  NSDictionary *header = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/json",@"Content-Type", @"application/json", @"Accept", @"iPhone",@"User-Agent",nil];

NSLog(@"url---%@",url);

NSLog(@"header---%@",[Utilities printJson:header]);


[SSNetworkClient initServerCallWithURL:url requestMethod:SSRequestMethodGET requestSerialize:YES headers:header imageData:nil imageDataName:nil parameters:nil success:^(id object) {
    completionBlock(YES,object);

} failure:^(id object) {
    failureCompletion(NO,object);

}];
```

Comment: whats the error you're getting ?

Comment: I am getting Nil As Failure Response :(

Comment: please post your code, might be something problem with your code, meanwhile you can read [here](http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/)

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you response of second url you are getting invalid json and which should be like this,

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": "on_time",
        "message": "U bent op tijd",
        "content": "Uw afspraak begint om *|afspraak_tijd|* ."
    },
    "slave": {
        "name1": "Dhr. sunny",
        "name2": "Meneer sunny"
    },
    "master": {
        "name1": "Mr beheerder"
    },
    "push": {
        "origin": "pubsub.pubnub.com",
        "pub_key": "pub-c-a6ca4c51-0a6f-475d-8f93-f53f48ba117b",
        "sub_key": "sub-c-97578f62-3587-11e3-be49-02ee2ddab7fe",
        "uuid": "sunny-5a323ac22cacff0004c2a717",
        "channels": ["5a29524f2b4faa000470384a", "5a323ac22cacff0004c2a717"]
    },
    "lobby_message": "",
    "contact_info": "/dyncontent/pk3rs51FpFUQkrHOJ0uBHg"
}
```

Above is the correct json which you will need to improve in your api response

And if you wont verify just create the json file with above json it will work perfectly with browser and with your .info api response json it won't work  so you need to improvise your .info json file response

My Mozilla browser Quantum version[image] response,